# AMD Radeon HD 8570 Dual Monitor DVI Splitter

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon, dvi, cable

I have a AMD Radeon HD 8570 card.  I would like to hook up a DVI to Dual VGA splitter.  I purchased this item: http://amzn.com/B0045JSO32

However it has too many pins and I was unable to even connect it to my card.  Can someone let me know what type of splitter I am looking for?

Comment: 'too many pins' - that will be because it's not DVI, it's DMS-59 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMS-59

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that splitter isn't DVI, it's actually a DMS-59 to Dual VGA.

DMS-59 is DVI-capable, but not directly compatible with DVI connectors. It can carry DVI information for 2 monitors simultaneously - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMS-59

Try http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=DVI+to+Dual+VGA+Y-Splitter+ for DVI->VGA, though bear in mind that unless your video card can handle dual DVI as separate monitors, similar to the DMS-59 spec, you will only get duplicated [mirrored] screens, not true 2 monitor output.

Comment: Does this look like it will do the trick?

http://amzn.com/B00P8OWGIW

Comment: It's a 24+5 so it will cover all eventualities, **if** your DVI socket can take the extra 4 pins above & below the flat pin. Zoom the amazon image to see what I mean & check your socket has those extra holes. There's still no guarantee your card can drive 2 independent monitors from those VGAs, though; you'd have to try it & see.